# npm always creating a min folder with node modules in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

when ever i run npm install ***whatever*** in ubuntu, it creates a min folder with node modules 
I have tried deleting the min folder expecting that npm installed it globaly  but it was not found.  [This is the picture of my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfJou.png)

Comment: what is a min folder with node_modules? is it 2 folders "min" and "node_modules"? do you have any preinstall or postinstall scripts in package.json scripts property?

Comment: @Emmanuel Uchewa can you paste your `package.json` here?